# How to connect the Gridview Control to the StorageFolder

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am working on a task to make a file browser application where you will be able to see all the list of files/folders in a folder  selected and able to open the folders. I used the folderpicker class to pick the files or folders from the system but i am unable to open the selected files in the Gridview. I am attaching the image of the code for this task.

```
 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        fp.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        fp.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        fp.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        StorageFolder sf = await fp.PickSingleFolderAsync();

        if (sf != null)
        {

            IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> read = await sf.GetItemsAsync();
            g.ItemsSource = read;
            g.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
           // g.CompleteViewChange();


        }
    }
```

Comment: It is advisable that code is pasted here and not linked. That way people can try your code.

Comment: I posted the code now. Please go through it.

Comment: What did you try for opening a file. I don't even see usage of IStorageItem.Path property.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by binding the data to the GridView.

Refer this [blog](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html)

Go through the [link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Build-your-first-Windows-Store-app/C-Part-4-File-access-and-pickers) for binding UI to the control

Comment: I am new to the coding i din't under stand the binding concepts

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500000/binding-images-to-gridview-windows-8

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/binding-controls-using-datatemplate-in-windows-store-apps/

Comment: I tried this by using the data binding concepts but i am able to access only one file selected from the selected folder